# Python не может найти фреймворк Flask

Tags: python, flask

Установлен python 3.8.10 в виртуальную среду устанавливаю Flask 2.3.2 (самая новая версия на сей момент). При запуске простого скрипта

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

возникает ошибка:
Файл "c:/fl/app.py", строка 1, из from flask import Flask
builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
Пробовал устанавливать Flask 2.0.0 Та же история
Пожалуйста помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

виртуальная среда  **venv** не подходит
нужно использовать **virtualenv**